# У меня есть объект на нём скрипт с диалогом. И мне надо что-бы после диалога этот скрипт исчез и появился другой

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть объект на нём скрипт с диалогом. И мне надо что-бы после диалога этот скрипт исчез и появился другой:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Npcquest2 : MonoBehaviour

{

    public bool quest; //переменная, которая обозначает взят квест или нет;
    public bool vis; // переменная, которая будет отображать диалог между персонажами;
    public string missionText; // Текст который будет отображать наименование квеста;
    public string missionTag; //Тэг объекта, который необходимо принести;
    private missionplayer MP; // подключаем скрипт MissionPlayer;

    void Start()

    {
        MP = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").GetComponent<missionplayer>(); // определяем что скрипт MissionPlayer будет находится на персонаже с тэгом player;
    }

    void Update()

    {
        GameObject MissionTagScanner = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player"); // персонаж у которого берем квест будет взаимодействовать только с тем объектом у которого тэг Player;
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.E) & Vector3.Distance(transform.position, MissionTagScanner.transform.position) < 2) // При нажатии на клавишу Е и при дистанции между персонажами меньше чем 2;
        {
            vis = true; // переменная vis принимает значение true;
        }
    }
    void OnGUI()
    {
        if (vis) // если переменная равна true;
        {
            if (!quest) // и если квест еще не взят;
            {
                GUI.Box(new Rect((Screen.width - 300) / 2, (Screen.height - 300) / 2, 300, 300), "Квест"); // то на экране отображается окно с названием Квест;
                GUI.Label(new Rect((Screen.width - 300) / 2 + 5, (Screen.height - 300) / 2 + 15, 290, 250), "Слушай, ты вроде тут недвано. У тебя даже топора нет. Сходика к Бармену он тебе даст топор да и заодно возьми мне кружечку бурбона."); // и текстом который описывает квест;
                if (GUI.Button(new Rect((Screen.width - 100) / 2, (Screen.height - 300) / 2 + 250, 100, 40), "Хорошо")) // при нажатии на кнопку Ok;
                {
                    quest = true; // квест взят;
                    MP.quest = true; // отображает название квеста на экране;
                    MP.MissionText = "Принести бурбон"; // текст квеста;
                    MP.ObjectTag = missionTag; // тэг объекта который необходимо принести;
                    vis = false; // все диалоговые окна закрываются;
                }
            }
            else
            { // если же квест уже взят;
                GUI.Box(new Rect((Screen.width - 300) / 2, (Screen.height - 300) / 2, 300, 300), "Квест");
                GUI.Label(new Rect((Screen.width - 300) / 2 + 5, (Screen.height - 300) / 2 + 15, 290, 250), "Ну что, принёс Бурбон?"); //то описание квеста меняется на другой текст;
                if (MP.MissionObjects) // если вы уже подобрали объект;
                {
                    if (GUI.Button(new Rect((Screen.width - 100) / 2, (Screen.height - 300) / 2 + 250, 100, 40), "Да принёс.")) // то появится кнопка да, при нажатии на которую;
                    {
                        quest = false; // переменная квест принимает значение false, т.е. не взят ;
                        MP.quest = false; // название квеста не будет отображаться на экране ;
                        MP.MissionText = ""; // убирается название квеста;
                        MP.ObjectTag = ""; // обнуляется тэг объекта;
                        MP.MissionObjects = false; // объект считается не подобранным;
                        MP.Money = MP.Money + 100; //добавление денег за выполнение квеста;
                        vis = false; // диалоговое окно закрывается;
                    }
                }
                else
                { // если вы еще не подобрали объект;
                    if (GUI.Button(new Rect((Screen.width - 100) / 2, (Screen.height - 300) / 2 + 250, 100, 40), "Нет")) // то вместо кнопки да, будет кнопка нет;
                    {
                        vis = false; // при нажатии на которую, окно просто закроется;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Если отвечать на ваш вопрос напрямую:

```
gameObject.AddComponent<T>(); //где T - имя класса, который нужно добавить
Destroy(this);
```

Однако,  подобная реализация квестов выглядит как-то жутковато. По идее, у вас должна быть одна панель, в которую для отображения помещаются данные квеста, а где-то у игрока должен быть журнал заданий.

Вообще сама реализация квестовых механик как таковых довольно объёмна и сложна. Не пробовали посмотреть в сети примеры реализации?

Ну и бонусом ко всему - .OnGUI() является Legacy кодом, который в более новых версиях выпилят за кошмарностью реализации.